# Java - for loop issues

Tags: java, class, for-loop

I have two classes. And I want the code in the for loop in the class below to run twice, however when I sent `int i = 0` and the condition to `i < 2`, it only seemed to run once. As you can see I've had to set it to `i < 3` to get it to run just twice.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LPrint {       
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("sender: ");

        String a = input.next();

        System.out.println("recepiant: ");

        String b = input.next();

        Letter one = new Letter(a, b);

        System.out.println("letter: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            one.body = one.body.concat(input.nextLine() + "\n");
        }

        System.out.print(one.getLetter());
    }
}
```

In the other class, the `String body = ""`, and it is only used in `String result = ("to " + recepiant + ":\n").concat(body + "\n").concat("regards,\n").concat(sender);`

Comment: You should test your hypothesis about how many times the loop runs... this is good debugging practice. Insert a System.out.println("Looping...") in the body of the loop and see how many times it prints...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that your problem comes from reading an unwanted string containing only a new line on the first iteration through the loop. I guess your input looks something like this (with either a space or a newline between foo and bar):

```
foo bar
baz
qux
```

After the first two reads the scanner will be positioned just after the token `bar` but before the new line immediately following it. The call to `nextLine` will read the rest of the *first* line (i.e. the new line character). It does not read the second line as you intended. When you read three lines you get these strings:

```
"\n"
"baz\n"
"qux\n"
```

To solve the problem you can either use `readLine` instead of `read` to read the first two tokens, or else you can add an extra call to `readLine` just before your loop and discard any remaining characters from the current line, including the new line character.

See this [code on ideone](http://ideone.com/jCD1e) that demonstrates the problem more clearly.